# Missing fonts in Scene builder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I use Scene builder to build some JavaFX app, whenever I try to select a font from right menu some fonts aren't shown in the list, what could be the problem?

I tried several solutions such as reinstalling the program, install the fonts then installing Scene builder, and tried different machines. I noticed that any PC that runs Windows 7 are working perfectly.

- Edit 1: After some attempts to try to fix the problem it turned out that Windows 10 store fonts in two separate folders, when installing fonts choose **Install for all users** and it should work.