# Fonts installed in Windows not shown in SceneBuilder

Tags: java, scenebuilder, javafx-11

I'm just starting with SceneBuilder and JavaFX. I've opened a test project and am checking out SceneBuilder. Added Label to the AnchorPane and wanted to change the font of the text. But I don't see any fonts installed in my system by me. I've already had some fonts installed in Windows before (Next Art, Montserrat, Bebas Neue). Neither of them is shown in SceneBuilder. I didn't find any helpful information on this problem. I've seen youtube videos where people choose their custom fonts directly from SceneBuilder. Am I doing something wrong?

P.S.: I know that I could simply write some code and integrate any font using CSS for example. But yet want to do it in SceneBuilder.

*(I use Java SDK v.14.0.2, JavaFX v.11.0.2 and SceneBuilder v.11.0.0)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I managed to make it work properly. Yet the answer was in an unanswered question here on the site :D.
Well, the reason why SceneBuilder doesn't see my custom fonts is that they weren't installed **for all users**.
*Windows 10* stores your custom fonts in this folder:

> C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts

But the system does it if you simply open the font and click "Install" button or drag-and-drop it to Start>Settings>Personalization>Fonts or C:\Windows\Fonts folder.

***To make your fonts visible in SceneBuilder on Windows 10***

0. If you already had them installed in your system:

   - backup your font/fonts from C:\Windows\Fonts folder
   - delete it/them from there (otherwise fonts will be doubled later)
1. Select your custom font/fonts
2. Right-click it/them and choose **Install for all users** option (but not *Install*)
3. Relaunch your IDE and SceneBuilder.

Now you should be able to choose your custom fonts directly from SceneBuilder.
That helped me, thanks to the user [d3f4lt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363752/missing-fonts-in-scene-builder).